# Problem when going back to main menu - C programming

Tags: c, menu, switch-statement, do-while, submenu

When this program is executed and case 1 is chosen, a submenu will be displayed. In this submenu there is an option to go back to the main menu, now this isn't displaying properly when chosen as it seems to be displaying the main menu twice as well as the default. This is the code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "functions.h"   //calls the functions.h file

    int switch1();
    int switch2();

    int main() {
        //Declaring variable
        char command;

        do {
            do {
                printf(SPLIT);
                printf("\nEnter choice to operate one of the following functions.\n");
                printf("1 - Operate using integer representation\n");
                printf("2 - Operate using textual representation\n");
                printf("0 - Quit\n");
                printf("Choice:");
                scanf("%c", &command);

                switch (command) {
                    case '1':
                        switch1(); //Executes function switch1
                        break;
                    case '2':
                        switch2(); //Executes function switch2
                        break;
                    case '0':
                        printf(SPLIT);
                        printf("\nQuitting.");
                        printf(SPLIT);
                        return 0; //Program stops
                    default: //Switch statement reaches default if no other cases are reached
                        printf("\nIncorrect input, please re-try.\nEnter choice\n");
                        break;
                }
            } while(command != '0');
        } while (command < '0' || command > '2');
        return 0;
    }

int switch1() {
    //Declaring variables
    char command;
    int *array, *iZeroed = NULL;

    printf(SPLIT);
    printf("\nInteger representation will be used!\n");

    array = generate(); //Executes function generate and sets the return to be array

    do {
        do {
            printf("\nChoose an option:\n");
            printf("1) Shuffle the array\n");
            printf("2) Sort the array\n");
            printf("3) Zero an element from the array\n");
            printf("4) Display previous zeroed out element\n");
            printf("0) Go back to main menu\n");
            printf("Choice:");

            scanf(" %c", &command);
            switch (command) {
                case '1':
                    array = shuffle(array); //Executes function shuffle and sets the return to be the new array
                    break;
                case '2':
                    array = sort(array); //Executes function shuffle and sets the return to be the new array
                    break;
                case '3':
                    iZeroed = shoot(array); //Executes function shoot and sets the return to be the element changed to 0
                    break;
                case '4':
                    target(iZeroed); //Executes function target
                    break;
                case '0':
                    return 0;
                default:  //Switch statement reaches default if no other cases are reached
                    printf(SPLIT);
                    printf("\nIncorrect input. Please re-enter an option\n");
                    break;
            }
        } while (command != '0');
    } while (command < '0' || command > '1');

    return 0;

}
```

This is the output I am getting when I choose to go back to main menu:

```
====================================================================
Choose an option:
1) Shuffle the array
2) Sort the array
3) Zero an element from the array
4) Display previous zeroed out element
0) Go back to main menu
Choice:0

====================================================================
Enter choice to operate one of the following functions.
1 - Operate using integer representation
2 - Operate using textual representation
0 - Quit
Choice:
Incorrect input, please re-try.
Enter choice

====================================================================
Enter choice to operate one of the following functions.
1 - Operate using integer representation
2 - Operate using textual representation
0 - Quit
Choice:
```

Comment: Why you are not using a space before `%c` in `main` function while you are using one in `switch1` function?

Comment: Wow, that small thing was it, thank you so much! Could you explain to me what a space before %c does exactly pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place a space character int the format string for `scanf()` before the input specifier `%c`, and it means `scanf()` should drop whitespace characters there.

You are already doing so in your `switch1()` function, so you should also do so in your `main()` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
 printf("Choice:");
 scanf("%c", &command);
```

Make it `" %c"`